# Custom Icon for VSCode Python Tests

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, icons

I want Python tests to have a different icon to regular Python files in VSCode so that it's easy to distinguish between code and tests. So one icon for `*.py` and another icon for `test*.py`. Seems like an easy thing to do but so far no luck.

It's not built into VSCode by default - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12493. You can associate file patterns to different languages, eg: plaintext which changes the file icon but then that breaks the linting etc for the test:

```
    "files.associations": {
        "*.py": "python",
        "*_test.py": "plaintext"
    },
```

Material Icon Theme doesn't support globbing. https://github.com/PKief/vscode-material-icon-theme/issues/330#issuecomment-428258408. IE The following doesn't work:

```
    "material-icon-theme.files.associations": {
        "*.py": "python",
        "*_test.py": "python-misc"
    }
```

vscode-icons doesn't support globbing either: https://github.com/vscode-icons/vscode-icons/issues/2617

Comment: you have to write a fileicon theme, or adjust one you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Material Icon` and `vscode-icons` developer explained that the `VSCode does NOT support glob naming for icon themes` block them to support this feature.

So I have tried this with `VSCode-icons`:

```
  "vsicons.associations.files": [
    { "icon": "pyret",  "extensions": ["test.py"], "filename": false, "format": "svg"},
  ],
```

It can change the icon of the file which names like `a.test.py` and keeps the `a.py` with the icon of python.

But the problem is the test framework can not discover the test which names like `a.test.py`, even like this `a..py`.

Such a pity. Maybe we should wait for the support of it.

Comment: Got it. Looks like Microsoft has a feature request open for this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12493

Comment: @Daniel Flippance Yes, it is.

Comment: Waiting to see if anyone else has a different answer

Comment: @Daniel Flippance Agree with that.